# Dropdownlist value reset with a selection of date from the calender

Tags: function, date, drop-down-menu, reset

I am using a dropdown list whose values are populated from database. I also have a calender function below
the dropdown. the requirement is that, I should be able to save the information to database, when i select 
a value from the dropdown list and a date from the calender. But, whenever I select the date, the selection in 
dropdown resets to the default '----select one----'(which appear when the page first time loads/ when no value 
is selected) and enter a 'BLANK' record into the database column.

Please Advise.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What programming environment does this question pertain to?

Comment: C#.net, javascript, sql server

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is ASP.NET, let us know if this isn't so.

You probably have AutoPostBack="true" on your calendar control and EnableViewState="false" on your drop down.  That means when you select something from your calendar, it posts the form back and it forgets the values that aren't saved in view state.  Actually, I'd recommend going with an approach that's more intuitive like ASP.NET MVC